# Function to check if value exists in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to create a function in JS like in title.

I have something like this, but whenever I write something in "else" part, like removing disable attribute for example, the whole function crushes. What I mean here, no matter what I will write into the description field - button becomes disabled, however text is displayed always correct, nevermind if else is fullfilled or not.

```
function CheckValue() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("description");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == filter) {
        document.getElementById("submitbutton").setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "Task with that description already exists. Please change its status or use other name for new segment.";
        message2.style.display = "true";
      } else {

      }
    } 
  }
}
```

I don't know what I'm missing. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Please include what you tried in the `else` statement so we can help determine why it crashed.

Comment: First of all the css style property `display`cannot be `"true"`. Have you tried with regular values `'none'` for removing element and `'table-cell'` or `'block'` for showing it?

Comment: `disabled` is a boolean attribute, but it doesn't accept `true` and `false` in the traditional boolean sense. The spec states "The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value." So, `disabled=false` will still make an input disabled. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute

Comment: Add disabled attribute: `element.setAttribute("disabled", "")`. Remove disabled attribute: `element.removeAttribute("disabled")`

Comment: This is what I had inside else:        
'`document.getElementById("submitbutton").setAttribute('disabled',"");
message2.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Please add your html to your post.

Comment: @remix23I've tried with "block", result is the same. Worth to mention that function is triggered with "onblur", when it comes to description input field.